# How can we determine $\partial\left\{w\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)\times \mathcal L^2(\mu):w_1+w_2=1\right\}$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a probability space and $$S:=\left\{w\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)\times \mathcal L^2(\mu):w_1+w_2=1\right\}.$$

> What is the (topological) boundary of $S$?

I'm a bit lost. Is there an easy approach to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would interpret $w_1+w_2=1$ as equality of equivalence classes, i.e. equality almost everywhere.

Hint: this is a closed set with no interior so it is its own boundary. [If $w_1+w_2=1$ you can find $w_3$ as close to $w_2$ as possible with $w_1+w_3 \neq 1$. So $(w_1,w_3)$ is close to $(w_1,w_2)$ but $w_1+w_3 \neq 1$.]

Comment: I think in order to obtain the closedness (in a rigorous manner) we need to alter the definition of $S$ to $S:=\left\{w\in\mathcal L^2(\mu)\times \mathcal L^2(\mu):w_1+w_2=1\;\mu\text{-almost surely}\right\}$, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, equality has to be interpreted as quality in $L^{p}$ space.

Comment: Maybe you can also help me in the question, which motivated this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3364359/47771.